# Play framework: broadcasting messages from actors by server-sent events

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, server-sent-events, enumerator

I have written a simple socket client with Akka-IO that consumes strings from a socket server (it sends strings separated by \n):

```scala
class SocketClient(endpoint: InetSocketAddress) extends Actor {
  override def preStart() {
    IOManager(context.system).connect(endpoint)
  }
  def receive = {
    case IO.Read(socket, bytes) => ??? ! bytes.utf8String
  }  
}
```

I need to broadcast the strings received using Server-Sent Events to all clients that requested it. How do I define an Enumerator with all messages received by actors to be available as stream from Play's controller?